# How to prepare a python script file for Windows so that it can be started with a symbol and run in an anaconda environment?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I created my own python packages that contains some script. It can be installed with

```
python setup.py install
```

Under Linux I can then run the script when the correct conda environment is loaded with:

```
my_script.py
```

Under Windows the script is not found although I specify it twice in the setup.py file:

```
config = {
    ...
    'version': '0.0.25',
    'scripts': ['scripts/my_script.py', 'scripts/my_script.bat'],
    'packages': ['my_package'],
    'name': 'ms_package',
    'data_files': [('scripts', ['scripts/my_script.py', 'scripts/my_script.bat']),
                   ('static', ['static/my_data.csv'])]
}
```

The script starts with a shebang:

```
#!/usr/env python
```

The file is found, but when I run it I get the message that this file has not app associated. How to set this up correctly under Windows? Do I need a second file that specifies an app?

I added the my_script.bat that loads the anaconda environment, but then fails with the same error. And when I put

```
python my_script.py
```

in there, it does not find my_script. So, I would have to do something equivalent to

```
python `which my_script.py`
```

Is there a functionality like this on Windows (Windows 10)?

I would like to have an icon for the user to click on. For people that don't know how to use the command line.

Comment: Assuming Python scripts are associated with the py launcher, as configured by Python's installer, use the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python` to search `PATH` for `python`. To run a registered version use `#!/usr/bin/python`. This will prefer Python 2 if installed. To require Python 3 use `#!/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: Nope, I am using Miniconda under Windows 10 to manage virtual environments.

Comment: Preferably your system should be configured to run .py files directly.  Check the current association for .py files by calling [`AssocQueryString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-assocquerystringw) using the following code: `import ctypes;` `cmd = (ctypes.c_wchar * 500)();` `size = (ctypes.c_ulong * 1)(500);` `ctypes.OleDLL('shlwapi').AssocQueryStringW(0x400, 1, '.py', 'open', cmd, size);` `print(cmd.value)`

Comment: If it fails with an OS error of -2147023741, it's a signed `HRESULT` error code with hexadecimal value 0x80070483, where 0x8007xxxx indicates a Windows error and 0x0483 (decimal 1155) is `ERROR_NO_ASSOCIATION`, in which case no program is configured to run .py files.

Comment: There is no such message. On the command prompt, I get: The system cannot execute the specified program. And a popup opens that no app is installed for that kind of program.

Comment: Huh? Run that code snippet in Python's REPL -- i.e. run Python and paste it at the ">>> " prompt.

Comment: The script is working. I want to install the script as executable though.

Comment: To be able to run "my_script.py" directly in the shell or by double clicking on it, some application has to be registered to open .py files. Windows has no knowledge of shebangs, but the application that handles .py files may handle the shebang. The py.exe launcher from the python.org distribution of Python handles shebangs. If possible, .py files should be configured to use it. In that case the command that I gave you to run will show the open template command as something like `"C:\Windows\py.exe" "%L" %*`.